# how to pass values from view to javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

So, i works in a project and i have a problem when i pass data from my view to my javascript,i have a foreach loop but always i get the last elements, **this is my view :**

```
 @foreach (var al in Model.alerts)
    { 
    <table border="0">
     <tr>
     <td rowspan=3><img src= '@Html.Raw(al.Owpicture)' class="img" alt="IMAGES"/></td>
     <td><label class="lb">@Html.Raw(al.cinOw)</label></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
    <td><label class="lb">@Html.Raw(al.Owname)</label></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td><label class="lb">@Html.Raw(al.OwpermitNumber)</label></td>
     </tr>
    </table>
        <script>
            //this is variable to pass
            var carNum = '@Html.Raw(al.carNumber)';
        </script>
    <input type="submit" name="Report" value="Report" onclick="IsReport(carNum)" />
```

**and this is my script code :**

```
 function IsReport(carNum)
   {
       var url = '/Home/IsReport/' + carNum;
        $.ajax({
        type: "Post",
        url: url,
        data: {},
        datatype: 'json',
        success: function (data) { alert(carNum); },
    });
   }
```

i tried everything but always i get the last **carNum**, so please if someone have any idea i will be very appreciate .

Comment: every time you loop through, you are overwriting `carNum` with the current value.

Comment: The key to understanding this is in being aware that the `<script>` blocks in which you set `carNum` are all executed at page rendering, and so only this variable takes the last value you set it to. So, by the time any `onclick` handler is run, it will always take this value. If you pass the value directly in the handler however, it will work.

Comment: Incidentally, since you are using jQuery, it would be worth looking into an _unobtrusive_ approach to attaching event functions - they're much better than legacy `onclick` handlers.

Comment: That's some horrible HTML right there. A table for each object, incorrect use of the label element and a very helpful IMAGES alternative for the images.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to try this way:-

```
<input type="submit" name="Report" value="Report" onclick="IsReport(@Html.Raw(al.carNumber))" />
```

What happens here in your code is that every iteration it will put the following in your html. and when you refer to the variable `carnum` it has the value from the last iteration.

```
<script>
            //this is variable to pass
            var carNum = '@Html.Raw(al.carNumber)';
        </script>
```

Another way is to use data attribute instead of using onclick event:-

```
<input type="submit" name="Report" value="Report" data-carnum="@al.carNumber" />
```

and in your script

```
$(function(){
$("input[name=Report]").on('click',function(){
....//some code
IsReport($(this).data('carnum'));
...///some code
});

});
```

Comment: thanks @PSCoder i already try this but onclick="IsReport(@Html.Raw(al.carNumber))" give me a syntax error !!

Comment: just try `onclick="IsReport(@al.carNumber)"` and by the way you are getting syntax error in your Razor? when does it say?

Comment: just a not, for data-carnum can i give it more than 1 variable

Comment: more than 1 variable means? how the value looks like?

Comment: You can give multiple data attributes say data-driverName=@al.driverName and access it as $(this).data('driverName')

Comment: for the script : IsReport($(this).data('carnum').data('driverName')); doesn't work !

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29066/discussion-between-pscoder-and-mohammadov)

Answer (score 0):

```
    function IsReport()
       {
            $.ajax({
            type:"Post",
            url:'/Home/IsReport/' + carNum,
            datatype:'json',
            success:function (data) { alert(data.carNum); },
        });
       }
```

The above answer display's the `data.carNum` value.